# Does dmcrypt/LUKS full disk encryption in kernel 3.0 have multi-core/multi-thread support?

Tags: encryption, luks

I've read a lot about how fast TrueCrypt 7.0 is with it's support for AES hardware acceleration and multi-core/multi-thread support. Will dmcrypt/LUKS offer the same performance enhancing features on a full disk encryption setup on Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

dmcrypt/LUKS does benefit from Intel AES hardware acceleration.

See [this article](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_aesni_dmcrypt&num=1) for some benchmarks showing the advantages of AES-NI hardware acceleration.

Comment: What about multiple CPU cores?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.
There is only 1 core being used. So a fancy 8 core or 4 core system won't be showing its full potential. And this post is 3 years old. And still no improvement on that.